# Subquery select values and save into enum in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, enums

I'm trying to remove a value from an existing postgresql enum datatype. My research tells me that I need to remake the enum data type excluding the value I do not want. My idea for accomplishing this is to get all values from the existing data type via

`select 
       e.enumlabel as enum_value
from pg_type t 
   join pg_enum e on t.oid = e.enumtypid

   join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
   where t.typname = 'alert_level' where e.enumlabel is not 'value i want to exclude'`

`create type alert_type2 as enum ('ABOVE QUERY HERE') ::alert_type`

and take these values I want and somehow insert them into a new data type

So my question: Is it possible to get values from a subquery and create an enum data type from the query results? Is there a better way to do this?

I've also tried something like this but I cant figure out how to exclude values from the select enum_range.

`create type alert_type2 as enum (select enum_range(NULL::alert_type)::text)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to exceute a dynamic query inside a function or `DO` block, example:

```
create type fruits as enum ('apple', 'pear', 'banana');

do $$
begin
    execute format(
        'create type fruits_without_pear as enum (%s)',
        (
            select array_to_string(array_agg(quote_literal(e)), ',')
            from unnest(enum_range(null::fruits)) e
            where e <> 'pear'
        )
    );
end $$;

select enum_range(null::fruits_without_pear);

   enum_range   
----------------
 {apple,banana}
(1 row)
```

Read about:

- [Executing Dynamic Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)
- [`DO command` with example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-do.html)
- [`format()` and `quote_literal()` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html)
- [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html)
- [`unnest()` and `array_to_string()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html).

---

Notes about used query.

```
select enum_range(null::fruits)

     enum_range      
---------------------
 {apple,pear,banana}
(1 row)
```

We want to transform the result to the string `'apple','banana'` to use it as a parameter in `format()`.
First, remove `'pear'` from the list:

```
select e
from unnest(enum_range(null::fruits)) e
where e <> 'pear';

   e    
--------
 apple
 banana
(2 rows)
```

next, quote the elements and aggregate them into an array:

```
select array_agg(quote_literal(e))
from unnest(enum_range(null::fruits)) e
where e <> 'pear'

     array_agg      
--------------------
 {'apple','banana'}
(1 row)
```

finally, transform an array to string:

```
select array_to_string(array_agg(quote_literal(e)), ',')
from unnest(enum_range(null::fruits)) e
where e <> 'pear'

 array_to_string  
------------------
 'apple','banana'
(1 row)
```

---

However, we should have done it a little simpler ;)

```
select string_agg(quote_literal(e), ',')
from unnest(enum_range(null::fruits)) e
where e <> 'pear'

 array_to_string  
------------------
 'apple','banana'
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you my good sir. Works excellently! Can you point me to any documentation that might explain your answer?